# Biggest View ever! How can I reduce this monster??

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, view

Once upon a time there was a View with many many Joins:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_BIGGEST_VIEW_EVER]
AS
SELECT {many many columns}
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.T_CUS_TSK_TASK WHERE is_deleted=0) T
  INNER JOIN dbo.V_CUS_GRP_GROUP G ON (T.group_id = G.group_id)
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_BKK_DISCOUNT_TYPE DT ON (DT.discount_type_id=T.discount_type_id)
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_BKK_CURRENCY DC ON (T.debit_currency_id=DC.currency_id)
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_BKK_CURRENCY PC ON (T.payback_currency_id=PC.currency_id)
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_BKK_CURRENCY FC ON (T.final_debit_currency_id=FC.currency_id)
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_GLOBAL_COUNTER D1C ON (D1C.company_id=T.company_id AND
    D1C.counter_name='PROFORMA_INVOICE_COUNTER')
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_GLOBAL_COUNTER D2C ON (D2C.company_id=T.company_id AND
    D2C.counter_name='TAX_INVOICE_COUNTER')
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_GLOBAL_COUNTER D3C ON (D3C.company_id=T.company_id AND
    D3C.counter_name='INVOICE_RECEIPT_COUNTER')
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_GLOBAL_COUNTER D4C ON (D4C.company_id=T.company_id AND
    D4C.counter_name='DELIVERY_NOTE_COUNTER')
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_GLOBAL_COUNTER D5C ON (D5C.company_id=T.company_id AND
    D5C.counter_name='BILL_OF_LADING_COUNTER')
  INNER JOIN dbo.T_GLOBAL_COUNTER D6C ON (D6C.company_id=T.company_id AND
    D6C.counter_name='CREDIT_INVOICE_COUNTER')
  LEFT JOIN dbo.V_SYS_BRANCH BR ON (T.branch_id = BR.branch_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_CUS_TSK_TASKS_ARRAY AR ON (T.array_id = AR.array_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_DRIVER D ON (T.driver_id = D.driver_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_VEHICLE V ON (T.vehicle_id = V.vehicle_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_STF_INVITER I ON (T.inviter_id = I.inviter_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_STF_SUBCONTRACTOR SC1 ON (SC1.subcontractor_id = D.subcontractor_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_STF_SUBCONTRACTOR SC2 ON (SC2.subcontractor_id = T.subcontractor_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_CUS_TSK_TASK_STATUS S ON (S.task_status_id=T.task_status_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.V_STF_SUB_LOCATION SL1 ON (SL1.sub_location_id=T.start_sub_location_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.V_STF_SUB_LOCATION SL2 ON (SL2.sub_location_id=T.end_sub_location_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_STF_CUSTOMER CU ON (CU.customer_id=T.customer_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_STF_CUSTOMER_SPLITTING_CODE SP ON (SP.splitting_id=T.splitting_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.V_CUS_TSK_CREDIT_FOR_TASK CR ON CR.task_id=T.task_id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_BKK_PROFORMA_INVOICE D1 ON (T.proforma_invoice_id=D1.proforma_invoice_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_BKK_TAX_INVOICE D2 ON (T.tax_invoice_id=D2.tax_invoice_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_BKK_INVOICE_RECEIPT D3 ON (T.invoice_receipt_id=D3.invoice_receipt_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_BKK_DELIVERY_NOTE D4 ON (T.delivery_note_id=D4.delivery_note_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_BKK_BILL_OF_LADING D5 ON (T.bill_of_lading_id=D5.bill_of_lading_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.V_CUS_TSK_CONTAINER CONTAINER1 ON (CONTAINER1.container_id=T.container1_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.V_CUS_TSK_CONTAINER CONTAINER2 ON (CONTAINER2.container_id=T.container2_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.V_STF_TRAILER TRAILER1 ON (TRAILER1.trailer_id=T.trailer1_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.V_STF_TRAILER TRAILER2 ON (TRAILER2.trailer_id=T.trailer2_id)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_STF_LUGGAGE_TYPE LUGGAGE_TYPE ON (LUGGAGE_TYPE.luggage_type_id=T.luggage_type_id)
```

One day the user asked the view for a query:

```
SELECT {many many columns}
FROM V_BIGGEST_VIEW_EVER
WHERE {column1}=1 AND
      {column2}=2 AND
      .......
      {and so and so}
      .......
      {columnN}=N
```

And the lazy biggest-view-ever worked and worked and after
5 minutes (!!) and not less it returns results.

Those tables had primary keys and foreign keys.

How can I reduce the time the query executes?
How can I reduce this view?

I searched on Google but I couldn't find anything that helped.

Comment: Does every query need the information from all those joins?

Comment: Oh. My. God. I second Marcelo's question, is all that really necessary?

Comment: Thirded. That is hideous - put it out of its misery...

Comment: Yes..Sql server don't know wich items the user chose to see.
I need all this info in order to build an object (really big object) that represent a task.

Comment: Most of the join is in order to get a name or a code of an Item.
For example  LEFT JOIN dbo.T_STF_INVITER I ON (T.inviter_id = I.inviter_id) is in order to get the inviter name and code. May this is a start?..

Answer (score 3):

Lets consider for a minute that the query represents a valid business requirement.

Just because the view is big doesn't mean that it should perform badly. The performance of selecting from this view is driven primarily by the **layout of the underlying tables**. Even with a view that left joins over 20 lookup tables SQL Server should return the result in milliseconds, provided the table `T_CUS_TSK_TASK` is properly indexed for the query being performed.

You must approach this just as any other query optimization. Investigate what are the main IO factors (`SET STATISTICS IO ON`), investigate the query plan, look at the cardinality estimates, consider if statistics are correct, look at the query missing index hints and consider how can you change the table(s) schema accordingly. You starting point should be this: [Designing Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190804.aspx). Even a cursory look at your (not provided in post) tables schema should reveal if, say, `deleted` is not the leftmost clustered index key then you certainly have a problem.

You current approach of blindly hacking at the query based on its **text** is completely unprofessional.

Now of course is *hard* to believe this query represents a valid business requirement. But, none the less, your view about query optimization and data model design ('Those tables had primary keys and foreign keys.') is primitive, to use a mild term. Read about index design, read about covering indexes, buy a book (like this: [Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: Query Tuning and Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621969)).